# Android: Handling screens that are the same dpi level but different

Tags: android, image, resolution, dpi, hdpi

I have gone through all of the Android docs about handling multiple screen sizes but I still haven't been able to find an answer to this question or how to handle this.

If there are two phones that have the same dpi level (such as both being hdpi) I can provide one resource for them and set the layout parameters as such:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="94dp"
android:layout_height="94dp"
>
```

The "icon" in this instance is large enough so that it will scale down to fit that layout in all cases. In an ideal world, I would assume that the icon would appear the exact same size on all hdpi devices, however when I tested it out on a LG G2x and a HTC Sensation, the image is smaller on the Sensation. So is Android always just using a factor of 1.5x when calculating the size the hdpi image? Is there something I can do to guarantee the size will be the exact same on all hdpi devices? Thanks.

Comment: what solution you propose about the quesion, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the system does use a standard multiplier for each dpi level (1.5x for hdpi for example). In order to get around this I just used the .xdpi and .ydpi values of DisplayMetrics and do my calculations off of those real values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to help you out with the proyect

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: I have already read that. The question is whether or not an image with a set dpi will really be the same size on all devices

Answer (score 0):

Usually when ever we want to do like this we usually use wrap_content. so once try layout_width = "wrap_content",layout_height = "wrap_content". Such that ANdroid SDK will look.

Comment: That is not always an option, as in my case, because there needs to be a set amount of space between the icons. Wrap_content is only helpful if I can also use Centering, etc. I still need a set out of space between icons. Any other help??